# How to omit 0 in a whole number Date string

Tags: android, date, datetime, android-date, android-dateutils

I have successfully changed the format of a date string from `yyyy-MM-dd` to `MM/dd`. Now the problem is that if the `month` and `day` values are less than 10 each, the format should be for example `2/7` and not `02/07`. How do I do this?

Here's my code:

```
    public static String cahngeFormat(String dateTime) {
        Date date = null;
        String str = dateTime;
        DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        try {
            date = formatter.parse(str);
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
            calendar.setTime(date);
            calendar.add(Calendar.HOUR, 2);
            formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd");
            str = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return str;
    }
```

Comment: have you solved your issue or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the format from `"MM/dd"` to `"M/d"` to allow single-digit output instead.

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("M/d");
```

Comment: I was looking if there were other solutions, turned out this is similar to what I'm doing now. So I'll check this for the solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
DateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
                    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
                    String timer = formatter.format(calendar.getTime());
                    formatter.setTimeZone(java.util.TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                    txtTimerCount.setText(formatter.format(timePassed));
```

i hope this is useful to you.